# Inner Tag Can't be grabbed - Python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to grab the text "More than 98 (30 Days Avg)" in this structure:

```
<div class="estimator-container">
<div> 
<span>Estimate sales per day for the rank</span> 
<input type="text" class="estimator-input">
<input type="button" value="Go" class="estimator-submit"> 
<span class="estimator-result">
<div>More than 98 (30 Days Avg)</div>
<div>More than 24 (Last Day)</div>
```

The website for reference is https://www.fbatoolkit.com/

My code currently looks like this

`driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@Class = "estimator-result"]')`

The `.get_attribute("outerHTML")` function confirms that I am selecting the correct element but adding /div to my syntax returns null, and `.get_attribute("innerHTML")` returns blank text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expretion to match the pattern.

Assuming that you want to extract the number, use this pattern:

`More than (\d+) \(30 Days Avg\)` ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/m1KGVA/1) for details)

Here is how to use it:

```
import re
str_in = """<div class="estimator-container">
<div> 
<span>Estimate sales per day for the rank</span> 
<input type="text" class="estimator-input">
<input type="button" value="Go" class="estimator-submit"> 
<span class="estimator-result">
<div>More than 98 (30 Days Avg)</div>
<div>More than 24 (Last Day)</div>
"""

pat = r"More than (\d+) \(30 Days Avg\)"
res = re.findall(pat,str_in)

print(res[0])
```

Which prints: `98`